# hide text box when combo box is reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am reseting a combo box based on another combo box. I have 2 combo boxes and when i am selecting `01` then `second combo` is enabled and when I am selecting an option from `2nd combo` then a `text box` appears, and when i am selecting 'please select' from `first combo` then `2nd combo` is auto reset(disabled), but why that text box is not disappearing?

When an option except first option is selected from second combo, I am populating a text box like :

```
$(function() {
    //This hides all initial textboxes
    $('label').hide();
    $('#secondcombo').change(function() {
        //This saves some time by caching the jquery value
        var val = $(this).val();
        //this hides any boxes that the previous selection might have left open
        $('label').hide();
        //This just opens the ones we want based off the selection
        switch (val) {
        case 'option1':
        case 'option4':
        case 'other':
            $('#label1').show();
            break;
        }
    });
    //I'm not really sure why these are here
    $("input").focus(function() {
        $(this).next("span").fadeIn(500);
    }).blur(function() {
        $(this).next("span").fadeOut(1000);
    });
});​
```

HTML

```
  <select id='firstcombo'>
   <option value="">please select</option>
   <option value="01">01</option>
   <option value="02">02</option>
  </select>

  <select id='secondcombo' disabled="true">
   <option value="_">- select -</option>
   <option value="option1">data</option>
   <option value="option2">data</option>
  </select>

  <label id="label1" for="option1">
        <input type="text" id="option1" />
  </label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not hiding because there is no event for your first combo in this code.

You may use below code to hide this

```
<select id='firstcombo' onchange="jQuery('label#label1').hide();">
   <option value="">please select</option>
   <option value="01">01</option>
   <option value="02">02</option>
  </select>
```

This will work for you.

Comment: This is the easiest way... if you want to do something more functionality on this then bind this as like second combo

Comment: thanks Shivam but if i have more than one label that is label1, label2, label3... then how should i edit this" `jQuery('label#label1').hide();` ?

Comment: @tom: you can use only `$('label').hide()`, If you are not sure about the ids your labels are holding.

Comment: Tom, Make function and call the function e.g. onchange="myFunc(this)"

and put your code in this function

Comment: But in this way $('label').hide() all label of that page will be hide

Answer (score 1):

checkout [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cdMAH/1/) here

```
$(function() {
    $('label').hide();
    $('#secondcombo').attr('disabled',true);    

    $('#firstcombo').change(function(){
        if($(this).val()===""){
            $('#secondcombo').attr('disabled',true);
            $('label').hide(); //added this
        }else{
            $('#secondcombo').attr('disabled',false);
        }
    });
    $('#secondcombo').change(function() {
        $('label').hide();
        var val = $(this).val();
        switch (val) {
        case 'option1':
        case 'option4':
        case 'other':
            $('#label1').show(); //u can use fadeIn() here as well
            break;
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: yes it is same but when 1st combo is reset then 2nd combo is disabled but that text box is not disappeared, i think slight modification is required in your fiddle, you are almost done